# Handling exception through a decorator in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to create a error handling decorator in django and where the logging happens in the decorator in case of an exception and the exception is raised back to the decorated function which then sends an error http response.

But when I try do this, If I add a Except block in the decorated function after the exception from decorator is raised back, then only the except block of the decorated function is getting executed and the except block of the decorator is left unexecuted.

**MyDecorator.py**

```
def log_error(message):

    def decorator(target_function):

        @functools.wraps(target_function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return target_function(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print('except block of the decorator')
                exceptiontype, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                filename = traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)[-2][0]
                linenumber = traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)[-2][1]
                mylogger(message=str(e),description='Related to Registration',fileName=filename,lineNumber=linenumber, exceptionType = type(e).__name__)

                raise

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

**Decorated function**

```
    @log_error('message')
    def action(self, serializer):
        try:
            ..................
            ..................
            ..................
            ..................
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data={
                "message":'link sent successfully'})
        except Exception as e:
            print('except block of the decorated function')
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 
                    data={"message" : 'error sending link'})
```

This is printing the line

> except block of the decorated function

and not the line

> except block of the decorator

If I remove the Except block from the decorated function then the except block of the decorator is getting executed.

Any help in understanding how this exception trace is handled in the decorators is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour: you run `target_function` from the decorator and you catch the exception inside it, so it is not seen by the decorator. I think you have to `raise` the exception in the `target_function`, as you done in the decorator. But as you have to return a `Response` in the except of the decorated function, the problem seems hard to solve...